# What is JWT and how to call google api php client

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am working on google api php client

I have question about JWT
What is JWT and How to setup JWT call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT is a JSON Web Token. Its essentially OAuth, but the token can also be decrypted to gain info about the user.

More here: https://jwt.io/